# Infinite scrolling in Autocomplete component from Mantine React

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, mantine

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling into the Autocomplete component of Mantine React as my data severely slows down performance if I try to load in everything at once. I would like to show the first 20 results of my dataset, and when the user scrolls down at some point the next 20 entries get loaded in, etc.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```js
//general input field, takes any string
export const ApprovalStatus: React.FC<GenericInputFormProps> = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  index,
}) => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
  const { classes } = useStyles({ opened });
  //access states from useGenericInputFormStore
  const inputs = useGenericInputFormStore((state) => state.inputs);
  const setInputValue = useGenericInputFormStore(
    (state) => state.setInputValue
  );
  const [value, setValue] = useState(inputs[index] ?? "");

  const { data, fetchNextPage, isError, isFetching, isLoading } =
    useUniqueDescriptions(20);

  //we must flatten the array of arrays from the useInfiniteQuery hook
  const flatData = useMemo(
    () => data?.pages?.flatMap((page) => page.descriptions) ?? [],
    [data]
  );

  const totalCount = data?.pages?.[0]?.totalCount ?? 0;
  const totalFetched = flatData.length;

  const handleValueChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputValue(index, event.target.value);
  };

  const autoCompleteRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  //called on scroll and possibly on mount to fetch more data as the user scrolls and reaches bottom of table
  const fetchMoreOnBottomReached = useCallback(
    (containerRefElement?: HTMLDivElement | null) => {
      if (containerRefElement) {
        const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = containerRefElement;
        if (
          scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight < 100 &&
          !isFetching &&
          totalFetched < totalCount
        ) {
          fetchNextPage();
        }
      }
    },
    [fetchNextPage, isFetching, totalFetched, totalCount]
  );

  //a check on mount to see if the table is already scrolled to the bottom and immediately needs to fetch more data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMoreOnBottomReached(autoCompleteRef.current);
  }, [fetchMoreOnBottomReached]);


  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        // dropdownComponent="div"
        maxDropdownHeight="280px"
        label={label}
        limit={20}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        data={flatData}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

This returns the first 20 entries of my dataset. However, when I scroll down to the end, the next 20 entries do not get retrieved. In mantine react table I managed to do this using an `onScroll` event for a table. Is there any way to also implement infinite scrolling into such a Mantine input field?